# navigating to url with variable javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, iframe, video

i need help with my code to make it right, all my code is fine i just need some one to edit it for me and add this few things

on the page i have video buttons, and iframe, and embed code area

when i click on video button, video 1 or video 2, the data-str will change in iframe src and in embed code area also it will get that data-str value from button to url to make it like this domain.com/test/page1.php?video=0_MfMUN_FNM

that is all fine it is as i want it. but the problem is, when i go to domain.com/test/page1.php?video=0_MfMUN_FNM it doesn't load the video that is in video 3 with data-str"0_MfMUN_FNM" it will load default one as it's on video 1 when 10 seconds are done.

so i want it to be like, when i go to domain.com/test/page1.php?video=0_MfMUN_FNM instead of domain.com/test/page1.php then video 3 most be selected because variable on url is "0_MfMUN_FNM" and after 10 seconds that should be playing instead of default one.

here's my full code on plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/LhxRjJXBnCGKGfW4ZLWO?p=preview

here's my javascript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //action listener for video_link class
      $('.video_link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.frame_src').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('str'));
        window.history.pushState({},"",window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?video=' + $(this).data('str'));
      });
        $(".frame_src").attr("data-src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/p9zdCra9gCE");
        var t = "p9zdCra9gCE",
            e = $(".embed_code").attr("data-content");
        e = e.replace("[videoID]", t), $(".embed_code").html(e), $(".video_button").slideDown(), $(".video_link").click(function() {
            $(".reloadframe").show();
            var t = $(this).attr("data-str"),
                e = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + t + "",
                a = $(".embed_code").attr("data-content");
            a = a.replace("[videoID]", t), $(".embed_code").html(a), $(".frame_src").attr("src", e), clearInterval(interval), document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none", $(".frame_src").show()
        })
    });
            </script>
```

Comment: `i just need some one to edit it for me and add this few things` - you've confused SO with hire a code monkey

Comment: Why aren't you at least trying to learn to do it yourself? Make some attempt —  then you can ask questions about the particular things you can't figure out.

Comment: @user099023 What everyone is trying to say is you should come here to ask a question instead of handing us code asking for people to do it for you.